# CreateJS / DOMElement over Canvas - Bug on Safari 10.1

Tags: canvas, createjs

When scaling DOMElement, it stays blurred until it gets completely out of the canvas (bug seen on Safari, but no bug on Chrome and no bug on Edge)
Check the code below:

```
  <canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150" style='border: solid 2px black'></canvas>
  <script>
  var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
  var html = document.createElement('div');
  html.innerHTML = "Test";
  html.style.height = '50px';
  html.style.width = '50px';
  html.style.top = 0;
  html.style.left = 0;
  document.body.appendChild(html);

  var gg = new createjs.DOMElement(html);
  gg.x = 0; gg.y = 0;
  stage.addChild(gg);
  stage.update();
  createjs.Tween.get(gg).to({x:300, scaleX:8, scaleY:8}, 1500);//, createjs.Ease.quadInOut);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
  </script>
```

Important remark: if the DOMElement is behind the canvas (transparent canvas), it never gets blurred.

Comment: Is this a question or a statement?

Comment: Actually, this is not a bug for CreateJS but canvas/text. The issue has been noticed before (ex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393224/translate-canvas-blurry-text)